# Creating an array of string_view elements throws error: unable to find string literal operator ‘operator""sv’ with

Tags: c++, c++17, string-view

I have the following (modified) code where I want to create an array of `std::string_view` objects.

I see this error when compiling corresponding to each line

```
unable to find string literal operator ‘operator""sv’ with ‘const char [8]’, ‘long unsigned int’ arguments
         "Sensor2"sv,
```

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string_view>

struct Abc
{
    static constexpr std::array<std::string_view, 6> SomeValues = {
        "Sensor1"sv,
        "Sensor2"sv,
        "Actuator1"sv,
        "Actuator2"sv,
        "Cpu1"sv,
        "Cpu2"sv
    };
    
};


int main()
{
    Abc abc;
    
    std::cout << abc.SomeValues[3];

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need `using namespace std::literals;`, which is ok, [**unlike `using namespace std;`**](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rs-using-directive).

See also [this question on here StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503152/is-using-namespace-stdliterals-safe), and, most importantly, [this item from the C++ Core Guidelines](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#sf7-dont-write-using-namespace-at-global-scope-in-a-header-file).